# No access on Samba share using Kubuntu 19.04 GUI

Tags: kubuntu, kde, samba

I have two machines running Kubuntu 19.04 and have troubles sharing files using KDE GUI. These are the steps I did to share a folder for a specific user (lets name him `myuser`) for read and write access:

1. On the machine A, I right-clicked a folder named "transfer",
   selected properties and then selected share. Since the system A was
   freshly installed, samba was not. The tab offered to installed it,
   which i did. Then I was able to select to share via samba in the
   tab.
2. I added the user `myuser` on the machine A, which matches exactly the         user on machine B.
3. I selected to share the folder with samba and
   allowed guest access to `myuser` and `everyone` with read and write access
4. With machine B, I navigated to the machine A samba shares. The folder "transfer" was visible. When I open it, a user/passwort prompt comes
   up. But whatever I enter into that prompt, access is denied. Using `myuser`, leaving everythin blank or the owning user of machine A - same result.
5. I then added a samba user on machine a using

   `sudo smbpasswd -a myuser`

   and entered the exact same password which exists on machines A and B. Still the same result.
6. Then i added `min protocol = SMB3` to my `/etc/samba/smb.conf`. Still the same result.

What am I missing?

This is the global part of my smb.conf:

```
[global]

## Browsing/Identification ###

# Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
   workgroup = WORKGROUP

# server string is the equivalent of the NT Description field
   server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)

# Disable SMB1 and SMB2
   min protocol = SMB3
```

Edit: This is the output of `sudo net usershare info --long` (at the Moment "Everyone" has only read access, `HTPC` is the name of machine A):

```
[Transfer]
path=/media/media/6TB 2/Transfer
comment=
usershare_acl=Everyone:R,HTPC\myuser:F,guest_ok=y
```

Edit: Output of `ls -al "/media/media/6TB 2"`

```
insgesamt 333
drwxrwxrwx  1 media media   8192 Apr 21 14:48  .
drwxr-x---+ 3 root  root    4096 Apr 22 07:43  ..
drwxrwxrwx  1 media media   4096 Dez 15 12:44 '$RECYCLE.BIN'
drwxrwxrwx  1 media media      0 Apr 20 12:39  Aufnahmen
drwxrwxrwx  1 media media 262144 Apr 19 15:40  Aufnahmen_win
drwxrwxrwx  1 media media   4096 Okt  1  2014  Dokumentationen
drwxrwxrwx  1 media media  12288 Okt  3  2018  Downloads
drwxrwxrwx  1 media media      0 Apr 21 15:58 'Kopie Backup'
-rwxrwxrwx  1 media media    435 Dez 19 17:36  mountBackup.bat
drwxrwxrwx  1 media media      0 Jan  6  2016 'System Volume Information'
drwxrwxrwx  1 media media  12288 Apr 19 17:10  Transfer
```

Comment: Please edit your post and add the output of the following command - without quotes: "net usershare info --long"

Comment: Output of "net usershare info --long added" above.

Comment: ls -al "/media/media/6TB 2"

Comment: Added output of ls -al "/media/media/6TB 2" above

Comment: Try changing the smb versions in the samba config file. Worked for me if the host is not supporting the highest version. v1 and v2 are disabled by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this issue is to edit /etc/samba/smb.conf and right below the `workgroup = WORKGROUP` line add this one:

```
force user = media
```

Then restart smbd:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

**Reason**:

The second "media" in the path /media/media is a user name and it has permissions of: `drwxr-x---+ 3 root  root    4096 Apr 22 07:43  ..`. The "+" at the end of those permissions indicates an extended permissions attribute that Linux automatically assigns for all local login users. It's real permissions look like this:

```
$ getfacl /media/media
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: media/media
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:media:r-x
group::---
mask::r-x
other::---
```

Linux creates it that way as a security / privacy thing in that only root and that specific user has the right to traverse that folder in order to get to any folder under it. A "guest" user or "myuser" is not the "media" user so they will never get to the Transfer folder.

Once samba allows the client user access they will be converted to the media user through the "force user = media" directive allowing them to get to the subfolder.